# Inserting records into a Microsoft Access database in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am inserting data to access 2000-2003 file format database using C#.  When I had a database with 2 fields the query works fine, but when there are more fields its is not working.

I have identical code for both and I am not able to find the problem.

```
using System.Data.OleDb;    // By using this namespace I can connect to the Access Database.

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private OleDbConnection myconn;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myconn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\leelakrishnan\Desktop\NewManageContacts.mdb");
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'newManageContactsDataSet.Contacts' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
           // this.contactsTableAdapter.Fill(this.newManageContactsDataSet.Contacts);
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'newManageContactsDataSet.Contacts' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.contactsTableAdapter.Fill(this.newManageContactsDataSet.Contacts);

        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
           // string query = "insert into Contacts (fname,lname,llnum,mobnum,e-mail,street,city,country) values ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + textBox7.Text + "','" + textBox8.Text + "')";
            cmd.CommandText = @"insert into Contacts (fname,lname,llnum,mobnum,e-mail,street,city,country) values ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text +  "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + textBox7.Text + "','" + textBox8.Text + "')";
            cmd.Connection = myconn;
            myconn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("User Account Succefully Created", "Caption", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            myconn.Close();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";
            textBox2.Text = "";
            textBox3.Text = "";
            textBox4.Text = "";
            textBox5.Text = "";
            textBox6.Text = "";
            textBox7.Text = "";
            textBox8.Text = "";

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

This is the code for the table with just 2 fields

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private OleDbConnection myCon;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\leelakrishnan\Desktop\Database1.mdb");
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'database1DataSet.Table1' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.table1TableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.Table1);

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Table1 (name,fname) values ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "')";
        cmd.Connection = myCon;
        myCon.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("User Account Succefully Created", "Caption", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        myCon.Close();

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox2.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Gaping vulnerability to SQL injection. Use parameterized queries instead of concatenating your SQL strings directly from user input.

Comment: @thomas Can you give an example? and why table with 2 fields doesnt have a problem?

Comment: Could you post the error you get ? Also, do the values you want to insert into Contacts contain single quotes (i.e. ') ?

Comment: What do you mean by "its not working"?  Do you get an exception?  If so please provide the exception details - In future you should try and post a specific question about your problem rather than large amounts of code.

Comment: @user561730 - As others have mentioned, we need more information to answer the question about error. As to the SQL injection, your query should look like `insert into Table1 (name,fname) values (@name, @fname)` and then you call `cmd.AddParameterWithValue( "@name", textbox1.Text);` and something similar for `fname`. Never concatenate values directly from a user entry into a SQL statement.

Comment: i get Syntax error in Insert Into statement

Answer (score 5):

The extra fields you are trying to insert probably have values that don't readily concatenate into a valid SQL statement. For instance:

```
string field1 = "meh";
string field2 = "whatever";
string field3 = "'Ahoy!' bellowed the sailor.";
var cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "INSERT INTO blah (x, y, z) VALUES ('" + field1 + "', '" + field2 + "', '" + field3 + '")");
```

Imagine what the concatenated SQL will look like, given the above input.

Worse, imagine the SQL you'll be executing if someone types this into your form:

```
field3 = "Bobby'); DROP TABLE Users; -- ";
```

Use parameterised queries via `cmd.Parameters.Add` or `AddRange` (described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.aspx)). The above example might be emended thus:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO blah (x, y, z) VALUES (@x, @y, @z)");
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new[] {
    new SqlParameter("@x", field1),
    new SqlParameter("@y", field2),
    new SqlParameter("@z", field2)
    });
```

Comment: OleDbParameter myParm = cmd.Parameters.Add("@fname", OleDbType.VarChar, 50);
            myParm.Value = textBox1.Text;
            myParm = cmd.Parameters.Add("@lname", OleDbType.VarChar, 50);
            myParm.Value = textBox2.Text;
           does this clear the problem for me ?

Answer (score 1):

This code for public:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = C:\Users\Mohammadhoseyn_mehri\Documents\Data.mdb");
```

This code for singup button:

```
 try
 {
     createaccount();
     else
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Please re-enter your password");
     }
 }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
 }
 finally
 {
     MessageBox.Show("Data saved successfully...!");
     con.Close();
}
```

This is the code for create account method:

```
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * from Login", con);
con.Open();

String ticketno = textBox2.Text.ToString();
String Purchaseprice = textBox1.Text.ToString();
String my_query = $"INSERT INTO Login (username, pass) VALUES ('{ticketno}', '{Purchaseprice}')";

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(my_query, con);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with databases, then mostly take the help of try-catch block statement, which will help and guide you with your code. Here I am showing you that how to insert some values in database with a button click event.

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
    @"Data source= C:\Users\pir fahim shah\Documents\TravelAgency.accdb";

     try
       {
           conn.Open();
           String ticketno=textBox1.Text.ToString();                 
           String Purchaseprice=textBox2.Text.ToString();
           String sellprice=textBox3.Text.ToString();
           String my_query = "INSERT INTO Table1(TicketNo,Sellprice,Purchaseprice)VALUES('"+ticketno+"','"+sellprice+"','"+Purchaseprice+"')";
         
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(my_query, conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("Data saved successfuly...!");
          }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Failed due to"+ex.Message);
         }
         finally
         {
             conn.Close();
         }
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score -2):

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)**
{
   OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   cmd.CommandText = @"insert into Personal (P_name, P_add,P_Phone)VALUES('" + txtName.Text + "','" +txtAddress.Text + "','" + txtPhone.Text + "')";
   cmd.Connection = con;
   con.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Recrod Succefully Created");
   con.Close();
   txtName.Text = "";
   txtAddress.Text = "";
   txtPhone.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: SQl Injection, use a parameterised query, always if sensible, without exception if it's user input.