# Generic function to append data into MS Access table using C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have written a function that is supposed to insert three items into a MS Access table using C#:

```
      public static void appenddatatotable(string connectionstring, string tablename, string[] headers, string[] values)
    {

            var myconn = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring);

            var cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO" + tablename +" (x, y, z) VALUES (@x, @y, @z)");
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new[] { new OleDbParameter(headers[0], values[0]), new OleDbParameter(headers[1], values[1]), new OleDbParameter(headers[2], values[2]) });
            myconn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myconn.Close();

    }
```

First, there seems to be a mistake and I cannot figure out what?

Second, is it possible to make this a generic function so that if you have say 10 columns it still works and dynamically resizes with `headers.Length`?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you think you have extra `{ }` in your method?

Answer (score 0):

You do not use SQLConnection / SQLCommand to connect to MSAccess. Use OledbConnection. Correct that and that should work. You can take help of [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971485.aspx) link for more information.

You need to make query of that type that can accept upto 10 column names. You need to write your own logic for that.

Comment: I was using SQLConnect as it was suggested here: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087748/inserting-records-into-a-microsoft-access-database-in-c-sharp) as preferred method

Comment: @npvh You are not understanding the link you have provided. It talks about parametrized queries ... nothing about type of connection.

Comment: thanks. I made it work with Oledb as you suggested. But the problem of manually specifing headers and manual resizing remains. Any ideas? thanks